# How do I get two spans to center on desktop, but stack and center on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a line of text split into two `spans`. I have them centred in a `div` on desktop and stacking on mobile, but for the life of me I can't keep them centred on mobile.

Heres the **HTML**

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <p class="center">
   <span class="inner">HERE'S THE BEGINNING OF A GREAT SENTENCE AND&nbsp;</span>
   <span class="inner">HERE'S THE END OF IT.</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**

```
 .center {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: table;
 }

 span.inner {
   float: left;
 }

 @media (min-width: 800px) {
   span.inner{
     display: inline;
   }    
   .center {
     display: table;
   }
 }
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3n9L.jpg)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHB8d.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text-align` on the paragraph to center it. The spans will be side-by-side by default, since they are `inline` elements. So that can be your default view.

Then in your media query, when the viewport width is < 800px, change `.inner` to be `block` which will cause them to stack on top of one another.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

 @media (max-width: 800px) {
   .inner{
     display: block;
   }    
 }
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <p class="center">
   <span class="inner">HERES THE BEGINNING OF A GREAT SENTENCE AND&nbsp;</span>
   <span class="inner">HERES THE END OF IT.</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael ... so simple! I see now that I was overthinking the problem, trying to force naturally inline elements to behave otherwise. Also, making the mobile viewport the default was getting in the way. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
span.inner{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the media query, you could use the text-align property on the parent and remove the left float on the inner span elements. Also use `display: block` to stack them.

So your css would look something like:

```
 .center{
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: table;
 }

 span.inner{
   float: left;
 }

 @media (min-width: 800px) {
   span.inner{
     float: none;
     display: block;
   }    
   .center{
     text-align: center;
   }
 }
```

In the media query, I took off `display: table` since you've already declared that outside the media query, but the rest is the same as you had it.

Comment: Forgot you wanted them to stack and not just be centered. Edited the answer